# Is there a way to change markdown shortcuts?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, markdown, code

I am using a keyboard with a French layout (azerty). With this layout, some shortcuts for markdown syntax are not convenient. For example inline code like `this` (`this` in between two `` ` ``) is generated by <kbd>Alt GR</kbd>+<kbd>8</kbd>, <kbd>Alt GR</kbd>+<kbd>8</kbd> (pressing <kbd>8</kbd> twice with <kbd>Alt GR</kbd> key pressed).

This is no very efficient and it is hurting my hands.

Is there a way to change such shortcuts in my user account (I didn't find anything). If not, should we (not all user use qwerty layout)?

Comment: Not an answer but Ctrl+K is another shortcut for code marking

Comment: You could use whatever markup is convenient then have a bookmarklet or user javascript or whatever else your browser offers to run javascript, to fix up the markup before posting the text.

Comment: @percusse thanks it is useful. Where did you fin this shortcut? Is it documented somewhere? Are there other ones?

Comment: I think I've just found out from the mouse over in the answering area. I don't know the main page for all this.

Answer (score 5):

I do not know a site solution, but you can try to solve his on your own:

For Windows there is [PhraseExpress](http://www.phraseexpress.com/), a text expander for Windows (free for personal use), and I guess there are alternatives for Linux and MacOSX, for Windows I know there are. I use this myself for instance to get typographical quotes like “” and ‘’ (also in German „“ or with guillemets « »).

Another “solution” would be: *Deal with it.* Some things are a question of familiarisation – on my QWERTZ keyboard in German layout all essential keys for typing TeX macros are only accessible via the <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd> key: `\command[optional]{mandatory}` (the typographical dash `–` BTW also with help of PhraseExpress). The `` ` `` backtick/gravis is a so called dead key here, to get it separately I have to press the space key afterwards. A possible consequence is something like this: `code`next_word (space key pressed only once). You can see this on StackExchange sites frequently.

*<sub>I already know, for typographical signs it works in MaCOSX and Linux much simpler without external solutions.</sub>*

Comment: The [Neo layout](http://neo-layout.org/) has ``\``, `{` and `}` ergonomically on the Mod3 level in the asdf/uiae row. `\`` is still a dead key, however. — For key-activated stuff, there is also [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) (under GPL license for whom it may concern). For recent versions of Windows, there is also [The Microsoft Keyboard Layout Creator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/us-en/goglobal/bb964665.aspx).

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel This is what, I meant with “for Windows I know there are” (i.e. alternatives to PhraseExpress), but nice to name some. For Neo layout I would need a keyboard, where I could see the layout on the keys, something like [Optimus Maximus keyboard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimus_Maximus_keyboard) in affordable amounts (? my poor English).

Comment: It *may* be a good idea to have the layout on the physical keyboard (the community is divided on this). I found it very helpful to learn the basic layout, i.e. the alphäbet, that I could write blindly after some time very easily. The best would be to have the full layout memorized (or at least the part you actually need). There are many ideas on [Neo-Tastaturen](http://wiki.neo-layout.org/wiki/Neo-Tastaturen) (scroll all the way down).